# Google Maps Autocomplete List Showing Behind AJAX ModalPopup - ASPX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

I have the following JQuery code that reads the string from a `textbox`. The string is supposed to be filled with addresses or street names, etc. to be found in Google Maps.

```
    $(function () {
    $("#txEnterStreet").geocomplete({
        map: ".map_canvas",
        details: "fieldset",
        markerOptions: {
            draggable: true
        }
    });

    $("#txEnterStreet").bind("geocode:dragged", function (event, latLng) {
        $("input[name=lat]").val(latLng.lat());
        $("input[name=lng]").val(latLng.lng());
        $("#reset").show();
    });

    $("#btnFind").click(function () {
        $("#txEnterStreet").trigger("geocode");
    }).click();
});
```

The problem I find is that the autocomplete list does not show in front of the AJAX Modalpopup, rather, it is under it, as you can see in the image. I can't find the way to make it show in front. I don't have a CSS class to modify the `textbox`. I am using the JQuery.Geocomplete.JS plugin provided here: [jQuery Geocoding and Places Autocomplete Plugin](https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/)

[image: Autocomplete image showing behind]

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, finally found out the solution. For the CSS that contains the code for, I modified it to be like this:

```
    .modalBackground6 {
    background-color: Black;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity: 0.7;
    /*z-index: 9999 !important;*/
    z-index: 1 !important;
}

/*for the panel*/
.modalPopup6 {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: Black;
    border-radius: 1px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    width: 950px;
    height: 720px;

    /*z-index: 9999 !important;*/
    z-index: !important;

}
```

I found the solution in this site: [specify z-index](http://www.telerik.com/forums/specify-z-index). I did not change anything in the jQuery. The CSS now modifies the z-index for:

```
            <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupGoogleMaps" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlGoogleMaps" DropShadow="false" TargetControlID="lnkFake"
            CancelControlID="btnCloseMap" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground6" BehaviorID="ModalPopupGoogleMaps">
        </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlGoogleMaps" CssClass="modalPopup6" runat="server" Style="top: 6% !important; display:none;">
```

Image showing how it works: [image: Autocomplete working]